# Dependency injection failed to inject for second service contract

Tags: .net, wcf, dependency-injection, spring.net

We are having problem with Spring.Net Dependency Injection when we added a second service contract.

Here's the setup:

One WCF project with two Service Contract (SVC file)
Service1 and Service2

Here's the Web.config

```
 <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="CrestService">
    <endpoint address="https://localhost/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" contract="WCF.IService1" />
  </service>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehavior" name="CrestClientService">
    <endpoint address="https://localhost/Service2.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpointBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" contract="WCF.IService2" />
  </service>
</services>
```

Here's the Spring.Config

```
<object id="Service1" type="WCF.Service1, WCF" singleton="false">
    <property name="ObjectA" ref="ClassA"/>
</object>
<object id="Service2" type="WCF.Service2, WCF" singleton="false">
    <property name="ObjectA" ref="ClassA"/>
</object>
```

Here's the Service1.svc markedup

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service1" Factory="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Here's the Service2.svc markedup

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Service2" Factory="Spring.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Here's the problem we are having.

With the setup display above we are able to get Service1 working properly and getting dependency injecting properly as well.  But for Service2 we get a runtime error:

> The type 'Service2', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

I've tried declaring the service name with fully qualified name in Spring.config, Web.config and SVC Mark-up to WCF.Service1 and WCF.Service2.  By doing this I was able to get both web service running without error, but the dependency injection fail to inject the objects in the web service.

I believe this is because the object id doesn't accept full qualified name in the spring config.

Does anyone have any clues to what might be the problem here?

Comment: try changing to `WCF.Service2, WCF` in the `service` attribute (in the .svc file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to the latest version of Spring .NET 1.3.2 seem to fixed the problem.  Might of been bad reference or problem with the downloaded files.